# C#: Waiting for a request to finish in C# 4.5

Tags: c#

I have a http request in my asp.net 4.0 application. I would like for the thread to wait before it continues on.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = client.GetAsync(requesturl).Result;

// I would like to wait till complete.

responseMsg.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Task<string> responseBody = responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Did you try to use the sync methods (not the async)?

Comment: It's .NET 4.5 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.110).aspx). Robert's answer is correct.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, but if you call .result, it should block the thread until it finish right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call .Wait() on the responseBody Task

Answer (score 3):

In 4.5 (your title says so) you can use `async/await`

```
public async void MyMethod()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");

    //do your work
}
```

To download a string you can simply use

```
public async void Question83()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var responseStr = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.google.com");

    MessageBox.Show(responseStr);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to call .Wait() but a better option is to use async

```
public async void GetData()
{
    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var responseMsg = await client.GetAsync(requesturl);
        responseMsg.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [async keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513(v=vs.110).aspx) and [await keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(v=VS.110).aspx), like so:

```
// Since this method is an async method, it will return as
// soon as it hits an await statement.
public async void MyMethod()
{

    // ... other code ...

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Using the async keyword, anything within this method
    // will wait until after client.GetAsync returns.
    HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = await client.GetAsync(requesturl).Result;
    responseMsg.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Task<string> responseBody = responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // ... other code ...

}
```

Do note that the await keyword does not block the thread.  Instead, after the remainder of the async method has been queued up, control is returned to the caller so that it can continue processing.  If you need the caller of `MyMethod()` to also wait until client.GetAsync() completes, then you're best off using a synchronous call.

Comment: You can retrieve the responseBody as a string using await too. You should also dispose of the client with a using block

Comment: Very good point.  I suppose that's what I get for posting incomplete code without adding anything to show that.