# Error in: C# XML serialization/deserialization

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

This is the actual code, not the complete code, but the main part of it.
Basically here I am writing a plug-in which implements some interface, and I need to store the state of the plugin because it runs multiple times during the whole process. But that storing of state through xml is generating an error

```
using System;
```

Comment: What is the content of the xml file?

Answer (score 5):

Your code won't compile. Use the `state` instance you have created instead of attempting to set non-static fields. Also make sure you properly dispose IDisposable resources by wrapping them in `using` statement:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Plugin
{
    public class state
    {
        public int a;
        public int b;
    }
    public class xyz
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            state s = new state();
            s.a = 3;
            s.b = 5;
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(s.GetType());
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\state\state.xml"))
            {
                x.Serialize(sw, s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

generates the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <a>3</a>
  <b>5</b>
</state>
```

Comment: OOPS! my bad. I corrected my code and even after wrapping it in using statement as you suggested, the same error remains: "There was an error generating the xml document"

Comment: Hmm, no, I have tested this code and it works perfectly fine. I will update to post a full snippet. Make sure that the process you are running this code under has write permission to the `E:\state` folder.

Comment: the file is getting generated, but it doesn't write anything to it.

Comment: See, my code is a part of a project, your code works perfectly fine if I run it independently, but if I write the same code in my actual project it gives error! Tell me how can I show you my original code?

Comment: Post the full exception stacktrace that you are getting.

Comment: The error message indicates an error about some abstract class and a null reference exception. I am afraid that I cannot help you without seeing your real source code. You seem to be attempting to serialize some abstract classes which is not supported.

Comment: or you can tell a way by which I can show you my code?  please reply

Comment: Try to narrow down the problem into an easily reproducible program that you could show here.

Comment: I have edited my code and narrowed down the actual code into the main part which has the problem, have a look at the code

Answer (score 1):

Its also not a good idea to serialize fields, you should use properties

```
public class state
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

state s = new state() { A = 3, B = 6 };

XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(s.GetType());
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\state\state.xml"))
{
   x.Serialize(sw, s);
}
```

Comment: Because you have better control and can do things like validation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't compile because you are using the name of the class (state) instead of the variable (s).

The following code works and uses *using* to ensure the stream will close even if an exception occurs:

```
        var s = new state {a = 3, b = 5};

        var x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(state));
        using(var sw = new StreamWriter(@"E:\state\state.xml"))
            x.Serialize(sw, s);
```

Comment: Why do you always repeat same answers like http://stackoverflow.com/a/10984736/932418

Comment: Coincidence maybe, but it happens sometimes: he starts writing his answer after you start writing yours. You post, he's still editing (and doesn't reload the new answers), and then finally post. *boom* duplicate answer. StackOverflow is not a thread safe posting environment ;)